# Can ffmpeg record more than two audio tracks? (Linux)

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg

I want to record four microphones, independently but concurrently and on the same clock (so they stay synchronized over long recording periods). I'm accustomed to grabbing two microphones (as left and right channels) using ffmpeg on Linux, and would like to use the same basic approach for the four.

I believe I've found several USB-based devices that will allow sending four multiplexed audio signals, digitized, through a single USB port, but it's not clear to me how I would capture this data into a single file. I've never worked with an audio file containing more than a left and right stereo track. (well, that and a video track, I suppose :)

Part of the problem is that I can't "just try it", since I don't want to buy the non-trivially-priced device if it's not going to be usable.

Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, does it "just work" when ffmpeg sees such a data stream, or is there some config I need to do (and if so, any hints on what, or where to find the information, would be most welcome).

TIA!

Comment: If the device outputs a single stream with 4 channels then it should be simple. Just cap and save. If it's 4 streams, you should still get all, but sync precision will depend on how the device packages the output and, likely, the driver.

Comment: I think by " cap and save "  means "capture (as normal) and save" and that you're telling me you think ffmpeg does handle n-channels, not simply stereo, and it will just work if the hardware does its part. (I struggled for a moment with "what am I putting a cap on, and how do I do that?"

Thanks, I guess I'll check the costs involved in returning it if it fails, and probably give it a try.

Comment: Yes `cap = capture`.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate your time.